# How to read data from XML into a structure using vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<work>   
    <name>Clean door</name>
    <time>10h today</time>
</work>
<work>
    <name> Clean floor </name>
    <time>12h today</time>
</work>
```

There are more `work` elements in the document, that's just a sample.  I have a structure defined in VB.net like this:

```
Structure work
    Dim name As String
    Dim time As String
End Structure
```

How can I read all of the `work` elements from the XML and store them in a list of `work` objects in VB.NET?  For instance:

```
work(1).name = "Clean Door"
work(1).time = "10h today"
```

Comment: What is the document element called in this XML document (the root element under which all of these work elements sit)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use either the [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) or the [`DataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) to deserialize from a file to your object model.

You will need to decorate the object model with the appropriate attributes in order to ensure that the serialization works as expected.